# Is there a convention for Java exception messages?

Tags: java, gradle, coding-style

I have been trying to throw exceptions with more information coming with it. I made it multiple lines since I want to make it verbose and help debugging.

```java
throw new RuntimeException("Something failed.\n" + 
    "Please provide another dependency on this class\n\n" + 
    "  MyClass object = new MyClass(depdencyA, dependencyB)");
```

However should I be doing it? Seems like many exceptions are one-liners, but I feel like its not verbose enough.

FYI, I am writing Gradle plugins, so please let me know if there are different conventions as well.

If there is one, please show me reference or documentations from authorities like Oracle.

Comment: I've never heard of a widely established convention. For production code, you may want to add some kind of unique identifier like ERR-314546 so you can refer to it easily from user documentation and have an easier time with automated processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions (and exception messages) should be as specific and concise as possible.

They should give enough information to pinpoint the problem and inform the user (or administrator) in how to solve the problem.

Your example fails on these points:

1. `RuntimeException` is very generic - select a more specific exception type (maybe some existing exception type, maybe some exception type you create)
2. "Something failed." is unnecessary - if everything was OK you would not throw an exception
3. "Please provide another dependency on this class" - if your class needs a specific number of dependencies the tell the user about it: "Only 2 of 5 dependencies supplied". Or tell the user what dependency is missing: "No DataSource found"
4. "MyClass object = new MyClass(depdencyA, dependencyB)" - this part assumes some call style on the users side. What if your constructor / method is called using reflection or through a method reference?
5. The exact location where the exception is thrown is also included within the stack trace - do not include this information in your exception message again

Comment: Does it make sense to categorize my exceptions by creating new Exception classes like `InsufficientDependencyException` and put my descriptions as message `Please provide another dependency on this class`? In this case I can also add custom fields to this `Exception` class.

Comment: @Nicholas adding custom fields to your `Exception` class makes only sense if the catcher of the exception knows your specific exception class and can access these custom fields. That generally means that custom fields should only be added to exceptions that you are going to catch yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are no general conventions.  However:

1. Throwing a `RuntimeException` like that is generally a bad idea.
2. Verbose exception messages can be overwhelming if they are directed at an ordinary user.
3. There are no guarantees that markup (like line breaks, tabs, etc) embedded in an exception message will be handled sensibly.  (For a start, you cannot predict the character width of the window in which the message will be displayed, and (even) whether a fixed-width font will be used.)
4. Internationalization ....

For the Gradle case, you can (should) check what other plugins do, and also see how Gradle handles multi-line exception messages.

---

Another way to deal with providing extra detail for diagnosis is to use the application's Logger to log an INFO or DEBUG event with the details ... *before* you throw the exception.

Comment: Exceptions should never be seen by an ordinary user! I know, that is the goal, not always reality, but I would not cater to what an ordinary user might see.

Comment: @TofuBeer - Yea.  But we are talking about a Gradle plugin here, and exception messages might be the standard (or only!) way to get diagnostics out.  (And you would hope that a Gradle user is usually a developer who has sufficient "cluefulness" to grok an exception message!)